# Is there a way to write into a CGPDFDictionaryRef (PDFKit)?

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

I can see a [lot of methods to get values](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpdfdocument/cgpdfdictionary#topics), I can even nicely map out the entire PDF into a dictionary (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454670/swift-cgpdfdocument-parsing/60097623#60097623)).

But I could not find a way to **write back into those dictionaries**. I really just want to turn off a layer visibility. Just set a boolean to `false` at `Catalog.Pages.Kids[pageIndex].Resources.Properties.MC(layerIndex).Visible`, then save the PDF.

I can see that you can nicely read/write annotations (even with the higher-level PDFKit API).
But **how do you edit the rest of the PDF contents** (like above)?
Is it achievable at all with Apple PDFKit?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't.

You'll most likely need a (very) pricey commercial framework to do this.

You may also find some free open source frameworks that claim to be able to do this. For example, pdfio: https://github.com/michaelrsweet/pdfio

(My personal experience of using that framework wasn't successful though).