# PDFDocumentAttribute custom Metadata

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, metadata, pdfkit

in [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocumentattribute), the default attributes is only 8

what if i want to read a custom metadata, let say `description`, how to use that key?

for reference: https://exifmeta.com/
it can read the `description`

[image: my pdf in exifmeta.com]

i have debugging the pdfDocument, but it only show the default metadata

[image]

Comment: Check how to read metadata of any file and not only PDF with PDFAttribute?

Comment: there is [File Metadata](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_metadata) but unfortunately, its for MacOS, not iOS cmiiw @Larme

Comment: It seems that it's not appearing neither with `FileManager.attributesOfItem(atPath:)`. It seems to be in the file though. I don't have many sample (is there per page?), but it seems to be "XMP". So you could iterate your PDF looking for the start of `<x:xmpmeta ` and end of `</x:xmpmeta>`, and parse the XML there... It's some work (avoid RAM use load, etc.), Adobe seems to give some SDK (I don't know the compatibilities, nor languages), there might be a third party iOS code that does read that XMP (like https://cocoapods.org/pods/XMPFramework ?)

Comment: this solution is worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/60097623/10797722